# How do I change color of selected TextInputEditText inside a Dialog and the positive and negative buttons text?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am quite new to MaterialAlertDialogBuilder in android and I getting a purple default color for actively selected TextIputEditText. I need to change the color of inputs when active to my own color, say maybe teal or green... and also the color for the action buttons on the dialog.

[image]

**Here below is some code:**

```
package com.indupendo.landing.ui.dialogs;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.indupendo.R;
import com.indupendo.databinding.DialogLoginBinding;
import com.indupendo.globals.utilities.Utils;

public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    DialogLoginBinding binding;
    View view;

    public LoginDialog(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DialogLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireActivity(),
                R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_rounded);
        dialogBuilder.setView(binding.getRoot());

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {
            Utils.INSTANCE.showLoginCancellationSnackBar(view, getLayoutInflater());
            dialog.cancel();
        });

        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Login", (dialog, which) -> Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Logged In",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());

        return dialogBuilder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        Utils.INSTANCE.showLoginCancellationSnackBar(view, getLayoutInflater());
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

**Layout XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_login_dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_dialog_title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/maroon"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_email_user_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_login_dialog_title">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ti_et_email_user_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/field_hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_email_user_id"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/ti_et_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/field_hint_password" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And here is the Theme**

```
<!--- Alert Dialog Theme -->
    <style name="MaterialAlertDialog_rounded" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/DialogCorners</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: it's your default color bro, go find the color in colors.xml. check which one is purple. it might be the accent color.

Comment: @Mohamad Okay bro let me check that!